# Gittle - "unexpected keyword argument 'pkey'"

Tags: python, git, python-2.7

I'm trying to use the library gittle to clone a git repository, I followed the examples in the readme, here is my code.

```
repo_path = '/path/to/dir/'
repo_url  = 'git@gitlab.myproject/proj.git'
key = open('/path/to/.ssh/id_rsa')
auth = GittleAuth(pkey=key)
repo = Gittle.clone(repo_url, repo_path, auth=auth)
```

When I try to run this, I got this exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gitCmd2.py", line 26, in <module>
    gitinit()
  File "gitCmd2.py", line 11, in gitinit
    repo = Gittle.clone(repo_url, repo_path, auth=auth)
  File "/.virtualenvs/test_gittle/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gittle/gittle.py", line 439, in clone
    repo.fetch(bare=bare)
  File "/.virtualenvs/test_gittle/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gittle/gittle.py", line 406, in fetch
    remote_refs = self.fetch_remote(origin_uri)
  File "/.virtualenvs/test_gittle/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gittle/gittle.py", line 363, in fetch_remote
    client, remote_path = self.get_client(origin_uri=origin_uri)
  File "/.virtualenvs/test_gittle/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gittle/gittle.py", line 327, in get_client
    client, remote_path = get_transport_and_path(origin_uri, **client_kwargs)
  File "/.virtualenvs/test_gittle/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dulwich/client.py", line 1076, in get_transport_and_path
    return SSHGitClient(host, username=user, **kwargs), path
  File "/.virtualenvs/test_gittle/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dulwich/client.py", line 879, in __init__
    TraditionalGitClient.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pkey'
```

The result of pip freeze (python2.7):

```
dulwich==0.9.5
funky==0.0.2
gittle==0.3.0
mimer==0.0.1
paramiko==1.10.0
pycrypto==2.6
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for your question. I was always dreaming of having git accessible by python lib, but all the solution I have seen are poor, including `Gittle` one. I even failed to install it - there are problems with packages not on pypi (resolved by `pip` switch `--allow-all-external`) but then there is still a problem with installing package `mimer`. Looks quite messy unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is issue filed at [github as TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pkey'](https://github.com/FriendCode/gittle/issues/18)

Workaround is described there too - using some cloned version of `dulwich`

Comment: Sorry to take to long to reply .. Thank you for your answer ! Indeed, I tried several versions of dulwich and it solved my problems.

Comment: @MrMetikha No worry with late reply, your question seems to live in it's own pace - it took 6 weeks from your question to my answer, so you are "just in time" from this point of view. Anyway, thanks for pointing me to promissing Python package related to git.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem below:

> TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pkey'

finally i solved it !!!!!
@8427003 thanks for your help.

1. remove all dulwich
2. download [dulwich-0.9.1-2](https://github.com/AaronO/dulwich/tarball/eebb032b2b7b982d21d636ac50b6e45de58b208b#egg=dulwich-0.9.1-2)
3. install the dulwich-0.9.1-2

   ```
   python setup.py --pure install
   ```
4. you will meet `refs.py not found error` and `not found git_line error`
5. download [dulwich](https://github.com/AaronO/dulwich/archive/master.zip), copy `refs.py` and `objects.py` into `site-packages/dulwich-0.9.1-py2.7.egg/dulwich/`
6. Then it works !

Answer (score 0):

Since the error is caused by the underlying dulwich distribution, there is a simple workaround for this problem, to solve. When looking into `dulwich.client` the problem is that dulwich uses systems `ssh` client to perform the operations. To resolve that you could use `paramiko.SSHClient` instead. This approach worked for me also with new versions  of `dulwich=0.14` fom PyPI:

```
import paramiko
import dulwich.client
from gittle import Gittle

pkey = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key(open('/your/private/key'), 'passwd')
repo = Gittle('/your/repo/path', origin_uri='/your/origin/repo')

try:
    from dulwich.client import ParamikoSSHVendor
    #for older dulwich versions -> The class was moved
except ImportError:
    from dulwich.contrib.paramiko_vendor import ParamikoSSHVendor
    #newer versions of dulwich

ssh_vendor = ParamikoSSHVendor()
ssh_vendor.ssh_kwargs = {
    'pkey': pkey
}

def _get_ssh_vendor():
   return ssh_vendor

old_get_ssh_vendor = dulwich.client.get_ssh_vendor  
dulwich.client.get_ssh_vendor = _get_ssh_vendor

repo.pull(branch_name='master')

dulwich.client.get_ssh_vendor = old_get_ssh_vendor
```

According to the dulwich code the `get_ssh_vendor` function is meant to be overriden by users.
If you are now running into the missing host_key error:
`paramiko.SSHException: Server '[0.0.0.0]:0000' not found in known_hosts`
This error is caused by that piece of code in the `ParamikoSSHVendor` class (`run_command()` method):

```
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    policy = paramiko.client.MissingHostKeyPolicy()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(policy)
```

I had to define my own `SSHVendor` class but `paramiko.AutoAddPolicy()` should also solve this issue.